# Как правильно из коллекции параметризованной другой коллекцией вывести данные в одномерный массив

Tags: c#

Всем здравствуйте, есть у меня массив `List<List<string>>readyList`. То есть в List содержаться несколько коллекций. Как мне получить простой стринговый массив,то есть в это массиве все элементы из всех внутренних коллекций. Думаю и не могу сообразить, вроде простой форыч не подходит.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать LINQ, а точнее [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Простой пример:

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> {"111", "222"}, 
    new List<string> {"333", "444"}
};

List<string> result = list.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Если без LINQ, то примерно так:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    result.AddRange(item);
}
```

Результат:

[image: Result]

Comment: Спасибо, да есть же Linq, я все время про него забываю). То что надо